# Decoding UART with gnuradio

Tags: uart, gnuradio, modulation

I was struggling with designing an application with gnuradio, that would receive and decode ASK modulated signal that is transmitting UART messages. It seems to me like an obvious thing to do, but I can't find any straightforward method, other than creating my own component, that would consume stream of 0s and 1s and produce a decoded string.

What I would like to accomplish is to connect the output of the binary slicer to one end of something and have decoded characters on the other end.

[image]

Is my approach correct? Is it possible to do with default gnuradio components? Or maybe that's not how it's supossed to be done?

Comment: That's GNU Radio 3.7. That's really legacy. Please don't start building new applications on it - it'll be progressively harder and harder to even get help with it, and we haven't put any development work into 3.7 in a long time. It doesn't even build anymore on very modern systems. Also, WX GUI is deprecated in late 3.7 and removed in 3.8; please use Qt GUI instead.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible, i made both a modulator and a demodulator, though i had to use a tcp sink and custom python code to go from bytes to chars